# nextLink with List Children on SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the List Children of a driveItem endpoint as described https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_children to list the contents of folders and using the nextLink property where appropriate. This works really well with OneDrive but when listing the driveItems inside a SharePoint site I get the first 200 items and a next link which just returns the last 2 and no further nextLink. I've also tried manually setting a $top value but this didn't help.

Not sure whether this a bug with the API but any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your descriptions, I assume you want to use the API 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists'.

Based on my test, when we list all the websites by TOP query,  the ‘NextURL’ will not exist in the response, if there are less than 400 websites.

Do your SharePoint site collect have more than 400 SharePoint sites? If not, how many site do you have ?

Comment: Apologies, I'm referring to listing the driveItems inside a SharePoint site. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Only two or three sites at the moment. The API which I'm using is GET /drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/children

Comment: If you have only two or three, the 'NextUrl' will not exist in the response. Because there are no more website shows

Comment: Please note that I'm talking about listing driveItems within a site, not sites themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express my meaning clearly. I want to confirm how many DriveItems are on this site. If there are less than 200 Items, there will be no more items after you query the first 200, so there is no NextURL in the response.

Comment: I have one with 602 driveItems. When I attempt to query it I get one result set with 200 items and a nextLink. Following this nextLink I then get a result set with 2 items and no nextLink. I assume are these are the first and last pages (looking at the file names).